# Check if an image is valid PNG file

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, ecmascript-6, png

I am having troubles with downloading images in binary format, sometimes a downloaded file is corrupted image.

So I need to check whether downloaded file is a valid PNG image.

I have already tried this library [Is-png](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-png), but it reads only first 8 bytes of the file and doesn't consider a whole file.

So I need to find a library that could check whether a whole file is valid png image or not.

Please suggest the best way to achieve this, maybe there are some great tools already exist.

Thanks

Comment: What is the criteria for "valid PNG image"?

Comment: If you also own the server, I suggest you to generate checksums instead of checking if a PNG image is corrupted.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thank you for the reply, but I am not owing the server (

Answer (score 0):

[GraphicsMagick and ImageMagick for node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) can detect corrupt images. You can use .identify to return an error if the image is broken.

```
var gm = require('gm');

gm(image).identify((err, data) => {
  if (!err) console.log('not corrupt image')
});
```